# Z3 should be able to verify this program?

Tags: z3, smt

I am a beginner user of Z3. Recently, I have been using z3 to verify some problems. Here is one problem I tried: (x < 0 && y < 0) implies x/y >= 0, below are the programs I wrote:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(define-fun assumption() Bool
  (and (< x 0) (< y 0))
)

(define-fun predicate() Bool
  (<= 0 (div x y))
)

(assert (not (=> assumption predicate)))

(check-sat)
```

When I use 'z3 -smt2 filename' to verify this program, it works and return unsat. However, when I later modify the program to:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(define-fun assumption() Bool
  (and (< x 0) (< y 0))
)

(define-fun predicate() Bool
  (<= 0 (div (* -1 x) (* -1 y)))
)

(assert (not (=> assumption predicate)))

(check-sat)
```

This cause z3 to timeout when I changed 'x/y' to (-1 * x)/(-1 * y) and somehow I need to add -1 there. I am confused why this happened and why multiplied by a constant makes this problem more complex.

Can somebody help figure out why this happened?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is very limited support for non-linear arithmetic, such as division where the divisor is a variable. 
So Z3 will do a best effort, but in no way be sure to provide decisions on every formula with non-linear arithmetical operations. So for example, you can enter Diophantine equations into Z3, but not expect it to provide sat/unsat answers.
Rather than trying some infinite search, Z3 may prefer to give up and return unknown.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This is just a comment instead of an answer. I have to do so because I don't have sufficient reputation to add a comment.)

Here is the quote from the [Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide) about integer division, modulo and reminder operators:

> Z3 also has support for division, integer division, modulo and remainder operators. Internally, they are all mapped to multiplication.

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const r1 Int)
(declare-const r2 Int)
(declare-const r3 Int)
(declare-const r4 Int)
(declare-const r5 Int)
(declare-const r6 Int)
(assert (= a 10))
(assert (= r1 (div a 4))) ; integer division
(assert (= r2 (mod a 4))) ; mod
(assert (= r3 (rem a 4))) ; remainder
(assert (= r4 (div a (- 4)))) ; integer division
(assert (= r5 (mod a (- 4)))) ; mod
(assert (= r6 (rem a (- 4)))) ; remainder
(declare-const b Real)
(declare-const c Real)
(assert (>= b (/ c 3.0)))
(assert (>= c 20.0))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

> In Z3, division by zero is allowed, but the result is not specified. Division is not a partial function. Actually, in Z3 all functions are total, although the result may be underspecified in some cases like division by zero.

It is unclear what is the behavior when the arguments are negative. In other words, the mapping to multiplication for these operations is not clear.